# Problemas con Deck y heatmap en R

Tags: r

Tengo un problema reciente que no me ocurría hace unos meses: la función add_heatmap_layer parece no funcionar. Puedo ver el mapa base pero no la capa heatmap. Incluso intento hacerlo con el ejemplo que encontré con los datos de sf_bike_parking (que encontré en esta web: https://rdrr.io/github/crazycapivara/deckgl/man/add_heatmap_layer.html), y ocurre lo mismo: Veo el mapa base pero no el mapa térmico.

El caso es que hace unos meses si pude hacer un heatmap, pero ahora resulta imposible.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a solucionarlo?

Dejo aquí el ejemplo del que hablo y el resultado que obtengo:

```
library(deckgl)

data("sf_bike_parking")

map <- deckgl() %>%
  add_heatmap_layer(
    data = sf_bike_parking,
    getPosition = ~lng + lat,
    getWeight = ~spaces
  ) %>%
  add_basemap()

map
```

[image: Mapa]

Comment: Para poder intentar ayudarte necesitaríamos poder reproducir el problema, trata de crear un [mcve]